# Feature map preprocessing for visualization of intermediate layers of CNN

Tags: neural-network, conv-neural-network, feature-extraction

I am trying to visualize the intermediate layers of my CNN and came to this tutorial in internet. In this code the feaure maps are being preprocessed before ploting:

```
channel_image = layer_activation[0,:, :, col * images_per_row + row]
channel_image -= channel_image.mean() # Post-processes the feature to make it visually palatable
channel_image /= channel_image.std()
channel_image *= 64
channel_image += 128
channel_image = np.clip(channel_image, 0, 255).astype('uint8')
```

What I don't understand: Why after normalizing, it's getting multiplied by 64 and added to 128?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I'm a beginner in this. Secondly, you did not provide a link to the tutorial but I'm guessing you are referring to [this one](https://github.com/fchollet/deep-learning-with-python-notebooks/blob/master/5.4-visualizing-what-convnets-learn.ipynb).

As for your question, I think it really depends on how the inputs were preprocessed (or normalized) before feeding into the model for training. I might be wrong in this but my intuition is that those 64 and 128 (the number the author added to the random noise image) are arbitrary numbers to deprocess the image for visualization later.

If you are using a custom model, those numbers might be different depending on how you preprocessed your images in your custom model. Hope this helps.